# If condition to ignore xpath when it is missing in one instance of the list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am currently trying to scrape LinkedIn Jobs Page using this piece of code:

```
# importing packages
import pandas as pd
import re

from bs4 import Tag, NavigableString, BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from random import randint
from requests import get
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from time import sleep
from time import time
start_time = time()

from warnings import warn

# replace variables here.
url = "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=&location=Egypt&geoId=&trk=public_jobs_jobs-search-bar_search-submit&position=1&pageNum=0&sortBy=DD"
no_of_jobs = 25

# this will open up new window with the url provided above 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
sleep(3)
action = ActionChains(driver)


# to show more jobs. Depends on number of jobs selected
i = 2
while i <= (no_of_jobs/25): 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div/section/button').click()
    i = i + 1
    sleep(5)

# parsing the visible webpage
pageSource = driver.page_source
lxml_soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'lxml')

# searching for all job containers
job_container = lxml_soup.find('ul', class_ = 'jobs-search__results-list')

print('You are scraping information about {} jobs.'.format(len(job_container)))


# setting up list for job information
job_id = []
post_title = []
company_name = []
post_date = []
job_location = []
job_desc = []
level = []
emp_type = []
functions = []
industries = []

# for loop for job title, company, id, location and date posted
for job in job_container:

    if not isinstance(job, Tag):
        continue
    # job title
    job_titles = job.find("h3", class_="base-search-card__title").text
    post_title.append(job_titles)
    
    # linkedin job id
    job_ids = job.find('a', href=True)['href']
    job_ids = re.findall(r'(?!-)([0-9]*)(?=\?)',job_ids)[0]
    job_id.append(job_ids)
    
    # company name
    company_names = job.select_one('img')['alt']
    company_name.append(company_names)
    
    # job location
    job_locations = job.find("span", class_="job-search-card__location").text
    job_location.append(job_locations)
    
    # posting date
    post_dates = job.select_one('time')['datetime']
    post_date.append(post_dates)

# for loop for job description and criterias
for x in range(1,no_of_jobs):
    
        
    # clicking on different job containers to view information about the job

    job_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/main/section/ul/li[{}]'.format(x)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(job_xpath).click()
    sleep(3)
    
    # job description
    jobdesc_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/section[2]/div'
    job_descs = driver.find_element_by_xpath(jobdesc_xpath).text
    job_desc.append(job_descs)
    
    # job criteria container below the description
    job_criteria_container = lxml_soup.find('ul', class_ = 'description__job-criteria-list')
    all_job_criterias = job_criteria_container.find_all("ul", class_='description__job-criteria-list')
    
    # Seniority level
    seniority_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/section[2]/ul/li[1]/span'
    seniority = driver.find_element_by_xpath(seniority_xpath).text
    level.append(seniority)
    
    # Employment type
    type_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/section[2]/ul/li[2]/span'
    employment_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath(type_xpath).text
    emp_type.append(employment_type)
    
    # No Applicants
    function_xpath = 'num-applicants__caption'
    No_Applicants = driver.find_element_by_class_name(function_xpath).text
    functions.append(No_Applicants)
    
    # Industries
    industry_xpath = '/html/body/div[3]/div/section/div[2]/section[2]/ul/li[4]/span'
    industry_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath(industry_xpath).text
    industries.append(industry_type)
    
    x = x+1

# to check if we have all information
print(len(job_id))
print(len(post_date))
print(len(company_name))
print(len(post_title))
print(len(job_location))
print(len(job_desc))
print(len(level))
print(len(emp_type))
print(len(functions))
print(len(industries))
```

The URL I'm trying to scrape is:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=&location=Egypt&geoId=&trk=public_jobs_jobs-search-bar_search-submit&position=1&pageNum=0&sortBy=DD
```

In the second for loop where I loop over the criteria of the job, in some jobs on LinkedIn, they do not put the employment type or the Industry! when it is looping on a list item that has them! it works just fine! but when it reaches a list item that does not contain the element it returns an element not found an error! how can I write and if condition to say that if the employment type or the industry type is not found in the list item! to ignore them and move on to the next one!

Answer (score 0):

> how can I write and if condition to say that if the employment type or
> the industry type is not found in the list item! to ignore them and
> move on to the next one

There's a couple ways you could do it, but having the output of the error would help diagnose the issue. Since you specifically want a way to ignore the exception, try this using error handling with selenium, as I believe you're getting a NoSuchElementException from your description:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
try:
    # line of code that is giving you an error, or the entire loop (not recommended).
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass # Or do something else useful like log the output.
```

You can read more about this particular exception, as well as the many others in selenium [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException).  Note you could just catch all errors and use 'except:' as well, if this error is not one coming from selenium, for example.